# Javascript sum total and overall total

Tags: javascript, html, sum

super new and learning at the moment to try and do a little car project site! im really struggling with being able to get the code at the bottom to total up all the values created by the check boxes

```
function checkTotalExtras() {
    document.extras.total.value = '';
    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<document.extras.choice.length;i++) {
      if (document.extras.choice[i].checked) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(document.extras.choice[i].value);
      }
    }
    document.extras.total.value = sum;                 
}
```

This part works fine and i repeat several times but i dont seem to be able to add up the totals

```
function DisplaySum() {
    var sum1 = checkTotalExtras();

    document.getElementById('document.extras.total.value').value = sum1;

    var total = sum1;
}
```

The HTML im trying to use to pull the total into the website:

```
<div>
  <form name="DisplaySum" style="width: 438px; margin-left: 12px;">
    Total: <input size="5" name="sum1" value="0" type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return sum, as your function returns void/undefined right now.

```
function checkTotalExtras() {
    document.extras.total.value = '';
    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i<document.extras.choice.length;i++) {
      if (document.extras.choice[i].checked) {
        sum = sum + parseInt(document.extras.choice[i].value);
      }
    }

    return sum;
    // document.extras.total.value = sum;                 
}
```

As there was no return, undefined would be passed to where you call it.

```
function DisplaySum() {
  var sum1 = checkTotalExtras();
  document.getElementById('document.extras.total.value').value = sum1;
}
```